# Can I create/draw my own custom polyline animation in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Once I find the 2 location points I will be using; can I create my own custom polyline animation in Google Maps?

I want to be able to show a dotted line animation being drawn as it goes from 1 location to the 2nd location.  So as the polyline is being drawn a dotted curvy "treasure map" type line will be drawn to the 2nd location point.

Thank you!

Comment: Check example [Animating Symbols](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-animate)

Comment: Ok, yes that looks like something I may be able to use.  But is there a way to have a freestyle type line (not straight) from 1 point to the other point?